# Path points don't move accordingly to scale factor

Tags: android

I'm making a makeup application. The application can detect some parts on the face, such as eyebrow and mouth, and draw them as a line, using a path from detection. the user can change the path by moving the points. But I have a problem when I'm making a pinch zooming, the image and the lines are zoomed perfectly, but I can't move the point after zooming. The points seem to stay at the same points when they were detected at the beginning.

This is the picture of the example of the app.
[image]

I use a scale factor from the onScale method to zoom the canvas.

I have a class of each part on the face. They have a points and draw method to draw a line. I don't know how to calculate the scale factor, from zooming operation, and the points of each line to move the points accordingly to the scale factor.

This is the draw method of the main canvas.

```
    float pivotX, pivotY;
    pivotX = width / 2;
    pivotY = height / 2;

    //draw and translate canvas
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, pivotX, pivotY);
    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    //draw eyebrow
    leftAdjustbrow.draw(canvas);
    rightAdjustbrow.draw(canvas);
```

And this is the draw method of the eyebrow

```
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (PointF point : points) {
        canvas.drawPoint(point.x, point.y, paintPoint);
    }
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    path.lineTo(points[1].x, points[1].y);
    path.moveTo(points[1].x, points[1].y);
    path.lineTo(points[2].x, points[2].y);
    path.moveTo(points[2].x, points[2].y);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}
```

Comment: if you are scaling the Canvas (Canvas.scale()) and then call Canvas.drawBitmap() & Canvas.drawPath() everything will be in sync

Comment: Where do you draw lines in your code? Can you give a piece of source&